# DOS- keeping portion of directory structure during xcopy?

Tags: batch-file, structure, dos, xcopy

I am a bit new to DOS batch files, and I am having a hard time wrapping my head around ways to solve my problem.

What I need to do: I have a large, nested source folder structure, let's say it lives here:

```
C:\dir1\dir2\dir3\file.txt
```

And I have a mirrored destination structure, although a portion of the root is different:

```
x:\dirA\dirB\dir1\dir2\dir3\file.txt
```

My current batch copies all files in the source structure to a destination folder, keeping the folder structure, which is what I want.

The problem:
The intention of my script is to drag a folder from the source structure above onto the bat file, and have it copy the files to the destination. What I want to do, is to allow the user to drag a folder from source dir, let's say `/dir2` and all of its subfolders/files onto the batch file, and have it copy the contents over to the SAME spot in the destination structure...

So in this example, the batch file should copy everything in and below:

```
C:\dir1\dir2\
```

into

```
x:\dirA\dirB\dir1\dir2\.
```

Fortunately (I think) my destination folder structure won't be changing, although the source might be in a different location on each machine. So, if there is a clever way to detect where in the source tree I am, and then replace a portion of the destination path... ???

Here's my simple script so far:

```
    @echo off
    set /p FILETYPE="What file type do you want to copy? (For example use txt, max, f3d, or * to copy all files.)"

    xcopy %1\*.%FILETYPE% c:\output /s 
    pause
```

Thanks so much for any help you guys can give! :)
Ken

**UPDATE:** Adding updated code sample here because I cannot get my comment to format or allow me enough chars. The stuff below may not be completely correct, I am just trying my best to be clear. I have figured out more since I posted this, basically I need to figur out how (or if possible) to use a string after delims, it only seems to check for each character...

```
    @echo off
    rem user drag folder onto .bat (left click, move folder using mouse onto .bat icon)
    rem %1 in ex is C:\random_folder\another_folder\proj1\area1\scene23
    set destRoot=X:\companyname\allprojects\proj1
    set rootDir=proj1
    rem assume %1 is folder dragged onto .bat file 
    for /f "tokens=2* delims=<foldername???>" %%a in ("%1") do (
        set part1=%%a
        set chunk=%%b
    ) 
    set finalDest=destRoot+chunk
    xcopy %1\* %finalDest% /E /EXCLUDE:exclusions.txt
    pause
```

I am hoping to create this:   "X:\companyname\allprojects\proj1\area1\scene23"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `x:\dirA\dirB\` part of the destination folder known? If so, the solution is easy:

```
@echo off
rem Get current directory, ie: "C:\dir1\dir2"
set curDir=%cd%
rem Eliminate the disk drive, ie: "\dir1\dir2"
set curDir=%curDir:~2%
rem Copy to right destination, ie: "x:\dirA\dirB\dir1\dir2"
xcopy *.%FILETYPE% "x:\dirA\dirB%curDir%"
```

I hope it helps...

**EDIT:** *Clarification to new comments requested*

Ok. There is a *source folder* and a *destination folder*. The program above assume that the current folder for the program is source folder, but this may be provided as a parameter if needed. The program achieve the following copy processes:

```
From source folder          -> To destination folder
C:\dir1\dir2                -> x:\dirA\dirB\dir1\dir2
C:\dir1\dir2\dir3           -> x:\dirA\dirB\dir1\dir2\dir3
C:\dir1\dir2\dir3\what\ever -> x:\dirA\dirB\dir1\dir2\dir3\what\ever
C:\XYZ                      -> x:\dirA\dirB\XYZ
```

If this is not what you want then explain it as concise as possible (use "files", "folder", "part of name" terms, not "I like", "what if", etc), and include three or four examples.

Also, note that for me *drag a folder* mean a drag&drop operation taking the source folder pressing the right button of the mouse and leave it over the icon of the Batch file. If you are NOT refering to this operation, please do NOT use "drag" term; use "copy" instead (please also clarify this point).

**EDIT:** *Solution to new requirements*

OK! You have not explained correctly before your last example! This problem is just about matching two names: last part of first name must match the *same part* in second name, and combine first name and the rest of second name. Right?:

```
First name:       X:\companyname\allprojects\proj1
Second name: C:\random_folder\another_folder\proj1\area1\scene23
Result:           X:\companyname\allprojects\proj1\area1\scene23
```

This is the solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem user drag folder onto .bat (left click, move folder using mouse onto .bat icon)
rem %1 in ex is C:\random_folder\another_folder\proj1\area1\scene23
set sourceFolder=%~1
set destRoot=X:\companyname\allprojects\proj1
rem Get last part of First name (destRoot) ie: lastPart=proj1
for %%a in (%destRoot%) do set lastPart=%%~Na
rem Delete from beginning of second name until that part, ie: result=\area1\scene23
set result=!sourceFolder:*%lastPart%=!
rem And insert the First name before the rest
set result=%destRoot%%result%
```

Or, combining the three steps in just one line:

```
@echo off
rem user drag folder onto .bat (left click, move folder using mouse onto .bat icon)
rem %1 in ex is C:\random_folder\another_folder\proj1\area1\scene23
set sourceFolder=%~1
set destRoot=X:\companyname\allprojects\proj1
for %%a in (%destRoot%) do set result=%destRoot%%sourceFolder:*%%~Na=%
```

Please note that if destRoot may contain spaces, it must be enclosed in quotes in the FOR command: `for %%a in ("%destRoot%") do ...`

Comment: Hi Aacini, I do know the destination folder... however, my issues is, what if someone drags folder /dir2 to have it copy, as opposed to if they drag folder /dir2/dir3 (and note, there are MANY folders, so they may grab something from C:\dirA\dirB\dir1\dir2 first time, but then grab from C:\dirA\dirB\dir1\someotherdirs\andanotherdir\ the next time.

Comment: Basically, I need to find a way to be able to drag and have it copy the contents (keeping the folder structure intact) and places them at the SAME location in the other tree. If it was ok to just copy everything over using the highest possible, common folder name I would do so, but I want my users to be be able to drag ONLY the needed folder (fully knowing they will get everything under that folder recursively) and have it place the contents to the right spot in the 2nd folder structure. (hope I am making sense here) :)

Answer (score 0):

Got this on another forum, seems to contain the answr I was looking for, sharing here for others:

```
@echo off

REM YOU NEED THIS

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM If the passed parameter string has any spaces you must quote it

REM we unquote it using ~

set PassedString=%~1

REM May as well do the same with string to split on
set DelimString=%~2

REM The delim string must appear exactly ONCE in the passed string

REM Replace the delim string with a symbol which will not be in the
REM path to be split, in this example I use @
set splitsub=@
call set tempstring=!PassedString:%DelimString%=%splitsub%!

REM Use FOR to split the modified string
for /f "tokens=1* delims=%splitsub%" %%A in ("%tempstring%") do set part1=%%A & set part2=%%B

REM Show that the 2 variables contain the desired substrings
echo Passed = %PassedString%
echo Part1  = %part1%
echo Part2  = %part2%
```

Example output:

```
C:\>splitstring.bat "D:\Backup\mystuff\programming\Visual Basic\project\ABCDE\DEF" "project"
Passed = D:\Backup\mystuff\programming\Visual Basic\project\ABCDE\DEF
Part1  = D:\Backup\mystuff\programming\Visual Basic\
Part2  = \ABCDE\DEF

C:\>splitstring.bat "D:\Backup\mystuff\programming\Visual Basic\project\ABCDE\DEF" "mystuff"
Passed = D:\Backup\mystuff\programming\Visual Basic\project\ABCDE\DEF
Part1  = D:\Backup\
Part2  = \programming\Visual Basic\project\ABCDE\DEF
```